# Need help using routes in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am little bit confused on how routes work in codeiIgniter. I have set up this following route

```
$route['myfirstest'] = 'Blogs';
```

I then set up a php file called blogs.php under the application/controllers directory

When I run the following URL

```
/code_igniter/index.php/myfirstest/hello/hello
```

I get a 404 message

However when I run this following URL

```
/code_igniter/index.php/blogs/hello/hello
```

It works find

Can anyone please help me figure this out..Maybe I am not getting the whole route thing correctly..

Comment: You also need to add this $route['myfirstest/(:any)'] = "Blogs/$1";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work for you

```
$route['myfirstest'] = 'Blogs';
$route['myfirstest/(:any)'] = "Blogs/$1"
```

This will also work for you.But I don't think this is your real purpose.

```
$route['myfirstest/hello/hello'] = "Blogs/hello/hello";
```

If you want any value inside hello function you can write this way

```
$route['myfirstest/hello/(:any)'] = "Blogs/hello/$1";
```

Remember for 2nd and 3rd solution you also need  to write

```
$route['myfirstest'] = 'Blogs';
```